# Using XHR progress events to monitor a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, xmlhttprequest, progress

I have a php script which is called by a javascript XHR function. In this script it accesses the Facebook API using a token (which is parsed from a Facebook redirect after accepting to connect to facebook).

When I add a progress event to the XHR object, it never runs, and when I log the readystates it gets to, only 2 and 4 are called. I don't think its necessarily a problem with my code, my only guess is that in my PHP script it gets the file contents of `'https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?limit=0&access_token=' + $token` (which json decodes its contents to use as an object which is looped through, adding each of the users' album(s) to a database) doesn't like the fact that I am visiting another url inside this XHR request.

Can anyone give me some guidance so I can make my progress bar 'load'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably to just use good old `readyState`